# O.D.E of the form $dy/dt=f(y)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working with the following equation: $${\rm d}y/{\rm d}t=y^2(4-y^2)$$

I have thus far done the following:

Graphed in an $F(y),y$-plane, found critical points of $0,2,-2$, and used first and second derivatives to find the slope and concavity to sketch the graph.

I need:

- to determine stability of these critical points, and
- to graph solutions in the $t,y$-plane.

I'm not sure exactly, but my guess is that each of the three points is stable. Also, do I need to solve the original equation so that $y$ is some function of $t$ to graph this in the $t,y$-plane?

I could use some hints on how to move forward with this. I'd rather not have any solutions - I want to understand this rather than get an answer and move on.

Comment: I guess you meant $dy/dt$ in the first equation?

Comment: Lol. Yes, that is exactly what I meant. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I've fixed it.

Comment: Note that $$\int {\rm d}t = \int \frac{1}{y^2 (4-y^2)}\,{\rm d}y$$

Answer (score 0):

To graph the $y-t$ plane you'll have to solve the DE. It is separable and easy, but in case you need a hint, try dividing both sides by $-y^2(y^2-4)$ and integrating wrt $x$. However if you don't have an initial condition, you'll have a family of curves in the graph(which looks pretty awesome, so don't worry).

Comment: I solved as ${\int y^2}$=${\int 4} dt$

Comment: Should've been $$-\int \frac{y'}{y^2(y^2-4)} \mathrm{d}t=\int 1 \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: $dy/dt=y^2(4-y^2)$     $dy/dt=4y^2-y^4$     $y^4dy=4y^2dt$  $y^2dy=4dt$ $y^2/4dy=dt$ integrating both sides gives $1/12y^3=t+c$ so $y^3=12t + c$  that doesn't work?